# Targeting specific pixels within a div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need to figure out how to only make a section of this div, transparent.

For example, the nav bar is 750 pixels wide. I need to make the first 75 pixels transparent. I know I need to use this code:

```
opacity: 0|initial|inherit;
```

However, how do I only apply that code to a section (75px) within the 750 pixel div? This is the ID and classes that I need to target.

```
#mega_main_menu.primary > .menu_holder > .mmm_fullwidth_container {
    background-image: url('http://visualicreative.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Nav-     Bar.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Website: www.visualicreative.com

Comment: You cannot target a specific percentage. I would recommend setting the div to have a transparent background, then place another div inside and set that with the background and only ave it fill the percentage of the width you need to give the illusion of transparency.

Comment: You may want to research CSS masking: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Answer (score 0):

you could create 2 div elements with the same background but the left one with transparency,

HTML:

```
<div>
<div class="bar bar-left">Transparent</div>
<div class="bar bar-right">Not Transparent</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bar {
background-image: url('http://visualicreative.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Nav-Bar.png');
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background-size:100%;
}

.bar-left{
    opacity: .7;
    float:left;
    width:75px;
}

.bar-right{
    width: 675px;
    float:left;
}
```

here is a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/BK3HS/

Comment: thank you very much for your response. A couple of questions: is the class (.bar) something I can incorporate into my #id (#mega_main_menu.primary > .menu_holder > .mmm_fullwidth_container {) or do I have to make a new DIV? If not, how do I mesh the two together?

Lastly, your JSfiddle example shows two bars stacked on top of each other. Is that just to illustrate the example or is that how it's suppose to be? This is for a nav bar so I can only have one bar.

Thanks again